# Unable to use "on_page" function of page object even after requiring in my helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, watir, page-object-gem

I am getting

```
undefined method `on_page' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Here is my spec_helper

```
require 'rspec'
require 'yaml'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'page-object'
require 'page-object/page_factory'

$url = "https://mail.google.com"
puts "Avinash Duggirala"
@browser = Watir::Browser.start $url

on_page LoginPage do |example|

end
```

Even after requiring page-object & page-factory I am facing this issue.
installed version of page object gem is page-object (0.9.3)
Same is the case even for version 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the page factory methods available in main (or anywhere else you want to use them), you need to include the module:

```
include PageObject::PageFactory
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some plumbing in your env.rb file under hooks to make these methods available to use

`require 'page-object/page_factory'
World(PageObject::PageFactory)`

from:https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/wiki/Creating-and-using-page-objects